# How to create new dictionary from multiple dictionaries when values from one dictionary are keys in other dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 3 dictionaries from which I want to construct a new dictionary.

dict1 = {'k1' : ('v1', 'v2'), 'k2' : ('v3', 'v4'), 'k3' : ('v5', 'v6')}

Each first value in the tuples in dict1 is a key in dict2.

dict2 = {'v1' : ('x1', 'y1', 'z1'), 'v3' : ('x3', 'y3', 'z3'), 'v5': ('x5', 'y5', 'z5'),}

Each second value in the tuples in dict1 is a key in dict3.

dict3 = {'v2' : ('x2', 'y2', 'z2'), 'v4' : ('x4', 'y4', 'z4'), 'v6' : ('x6', 'y6', 'z6')}

The new dictionary has:

- new defined keys a formatted string like ‘q{i}’.
- the values of the keys from dict2 and dict3 (which where in the same tuple in dict1), stored together in a tuple.

dict4 = { 'q1' : ('x1', 'y1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2', 'z2'),
'q2' : ('x3', 'y3', 'z3', 'x4', 'y4', 'z4'),
'q3' : ('x5', 'y5', 'z5', 'x6', 'y6', 'z6')}

Comment: Could you fix the fancy quotes in your code examples? As it is now, Python throws an error: `SyntaxError: invalid character '“' (U+201C)`.

Comment: `v1` is in dict2 twice, and also in dict3

Comment: I removed the fancy quotes which trowed an error and corrected the variable v1 which was mentioned twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Bharel's excellent answer, you can wrap `dict1.values()` in `enumerate` to be able to get the desired key names:

```
dict4 = {f'q{i}': dict2[v1] + dict3[v2] for i, (v1, v2) in enumerate(dict1.values(), 1)}
```

Output:

```
{'q1': ('x1', 'y1', 'z1', 'x2', 'y2', 'z2'),
 'q2': ('x3', 'y3', 'z3', 'x4', 'y4', 'z4'),
 'q3': ('x5', 'y5', 'z5', 'x6', 'y6', 'z6')}
```

Comment: What if the v and k variables can only be generated by using formatted strings? I just added this to my description.

Comment: @mempy I don't see how that would change anything since you're creating a new dict from already constructed dicts. Could you show an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: I see what you mean, you are right. It’s working correctly now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line:

```
output = {key: dict2[v1] + dict3[v2] for key, (v1, v2) in dict1.items()}
```

Since we don't know what are the new keys, I used the original `dict1` keys as keys for the new `dict4`.